# IntelliJ feature file undefined step reference with import io.cucumber.java.en.Given

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, intellij

I have a feature file with the following:

```
Scenario: Test something
    Given I do something to test something
```

My step definition:

```
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
...
@Given("I do something to test something")
public void doSomething()
{
....
}
```

From my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

With the above, I can run my code using my runner, but in the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) the step in the feature file is complaining about an *"Undefined step reference"*. When I CTRL-left-click the step, it does not take me to the method for the step.

If I change my import to:

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
```

Everything works as expected (i.e. the step is found), but then I get a warning about import cucumber.api.java.en.Given being deprecated (and the "Given" in my code has a line going through it).

[image]

How can I make my the feature file work so that when I CTRL-Left-Click on a step it will take me to the method for the step, but also avoid the "deprecated" warning?

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ Cucumber plugin? It may be due some mismatch over your Cucumber version. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7212-cucumber-for-java (I will transform it in an answer if that's the case)

Comment: Hi @JoãoFarias. Unfortunately, the 192.x releases don't work with my version of IntelliJ (2019.1.3). I'm downloading 2019.2, and will then try the latest version of the Cucumber for Java plugin.

Comment: Hi @JoãoFarias. Unfortunately, upgrading to the latest Cucumber for Java plugin did not work for me. The issue persists. When I use the deprecated packages (e.g. `import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;`), then everything works fine (except I get the "deprecated" warning and lines through deprecated annotations).

Comment: I did clean reinstall of IJ Idea 2019.3.4 (193.6911.*) and installed latest plugins for that version Gherkin (193.*) and Cucumber for Java (193.*), but I still experience the same issues. My Cucumber package versions are 4.7.2. I don't have Substeps plugin as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue with our team's project.  If you update to the latest version of IntelliJ (Currently 192.6x) it does support the latest version of the Cucumber for Java plugin now.  After updating you will be able to change from using cucumber.api.java.en to io.cucumber.java.en

If you are updating from 191.x you may need to reinstall the Cucumber for Java plugin as well as update your other plugins such as gherkin.

Comment: it works for me

Comment: I'm on Idea 2019.3.4 (193.*) with the latest plugins (also version 193.*) for it, but some steps are not mapped, while tests themselves work.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar kind of issue in intelliJ.

In InjelliJ Settings -> Plugins (Ctrl+Alt+S), *deselect* the plugin **Substeps IntelliJ Plugin**. And install **Cucumber for Java** and **Gherkin** plugin. Restart IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to FileType

Under Cucumber Scenario, Add *Feature. It will work.

Dont waste time in doing all other stuffs.